# Kafka-connect-hdfs : Tiny files and difference between rotate.interval settings

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

When i config the hdfs connector, i set the "`flush.size=3`" and "`rotate.interval.ms=5000`" and what confused me is if it will generate lots of trivial  files such as: **tens of thousands of files**...

[image: files]

I don't want to be more trivial files, is there any other possible solution?

Besides, what's the difference between `rotate.interval.ms` and `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `rotate.interval.ms=5000` will invoke file commits every 5 secs.You might want to leave it untouched as it is disabled by default unless the data ingestion rate is low and the connector didn’t write enough messages to commit files.

The difference between rotate.interval.ms and rotate.schedule.interval.ms is that:

> `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` will make sure commits are done at
>   scheduled time regardless of previous commits.This configuration is
>   useful when you have to commit your data based on current server time,
>   like at the beginning of every hour.

`rotate.interval.ms` will invoke file commits every 'n' ms and ensures that file commits are invoked every 'n' ms.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Every invoke of file commits will generates new files?
If i disable rotate.interval.ms and rotate.schedule.interval.ms configuration,then how long the connector will invoke file commits? Does this have anything to do with memory size?